# Setting limits with scale_x_time

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like that the x-axis to start at 04:00 (today) and to end at 03:45 (tomorrow).  There is still data to be captured after 00:00. Any suggestions?

Update:

Sample code based on suggestions works fine but when I change the POSIXct date from today to tomorrow still does not considers the data after 00:00.

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) +
     geom_line(size=1.5)+
    labs(x="Time", y="% ", title="")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=20), 
         axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12),
        strip.text = element_text(size=6, face="bold"))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) + 
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = '%T', 
                    limits = c(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'UTC'), 
                             as.POSIXct('1970-01-02 03:45:00', tz = 'UTC')), 
                   breaks = '1 hour')
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(time = structure(c(14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 
18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 
26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 
34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 
42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 
50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 
58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 
66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 70200, 71100, 72000, 72900, 73800, 
74700, 75600, 76500, 77400, 78300, 79200, 80100, 81000, 81900, 
82800, 83700, 84600, 85500, 0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 
6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 13500, 14400, 
15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 21600, 22500, 
23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 29700, 30600, 
31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 37800, 38700, 
39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 45900, 46800, 
47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 54000, 54900, 
55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 62100, 63000, 
63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 70200, 71100, 
72000, 72900, 73800, 74700, 75600, 76500, 77400, 78300, 79200, 
80100, 81000, 81900, 82800, 83700, 84600, 85500, 0, 900, 1800, 
2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 
11700, 12600, 13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 
19800, 20700, 21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 
27900, 28800, 29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 
36000, 36900, 37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 
44100, 45000, 45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 
52200, 53100, 54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 
60300, 61200, 62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 
68400, 69300, 70200, 71100, 72000, 72900, 73800, 74700, 75600, 
76500, 77400, 78300, 79200, 80100, 81000, 81900, 82800, 83700, 
84600, 85500, 0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 
8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 
17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 
25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 
33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 
41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 
49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 
57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 
65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 70200, 71100, 72000, 72900, 
73800, 74700, 75600, 76500, 77400, 78300, 79200, 80100, 81000, 
81900, 82800, 83700, 84600, 85500, 0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 
4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 
13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 
21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 
29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 
37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 
45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 
54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 
62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 
70200, 71100, 72000, 72900, 73800, 74700, 75600, 76500, 77400, 
78300, 79200, 80100, 81000, 81900, 82800, 83700, 84600, 85500, 
0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 
9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 13500), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), variable = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.035714286, 
0.035714286, 0.035714286, 0.071428571, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.428571429, 0.428571429, 0.5, 0.535714286, 0.75, 0.75, 0.785714286, 
0.75, 0.821428571, 0.75, 0.857142857, 0.857142857, 0.857142857, 
0.857142857, 0.857142857, 0.857142857, 0.892857143, 0.928571429, 
0.928571429, 0.928571429, 0.892857143, 0.892857143, 0.785714286, 
0.821428571, 0.964285714, 0.964285714, 0.964285714, 0.964285714, 
0.964285714, 0.964285714, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.964285714, 0.75, 0.857142857, 
0.857142857, 0.892857143, 0.892857143, 0.892857143, 0.892857143, 
0.892857143, 0.857142857, 0.857142857, 0.785714286, 0.75, 0.535714286, 
0.535714286, 0.535714286, 0.535714286, 0.464285714, 0.464285714, 
0.428571429, 0.357142857, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.178571429, 
0.178571429, 0.178571429, 0.178571429, 0.142857143, 0.142857143, 
0.142857143, 0.107142857, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.009302326, 0.009302326, 0.037209302, 0.055813953, 
0.069767442, 0.069767442, 0.16744186, 0.176744186, 0.190697674, 
0.190697674, 0.31627907, 0.339534884, 0.423255814, 0.455813953, 
0.627906977, 0.679069767, 0.781395349, 0.795348837, 0.823255814, 
0.865116279, 0.902325581, 0.925581395, 0.911627907, 0.91627907, 
0.893023256, 0.91627907, 0.981395349, 0.990697674, 0.990697674, 
1, 0.962790698, 0.962790698, 0.925581395, 0.893023256, 0.83255814, 
0.83255814, 0.888372093, 0.906976744, 0.934883721, 0.944186047, 
0.962790698, 0.976744186, 0.953488372, 0.953488372, 0.990697674, 
0.995348837, 0.934883721, 0.920930233, 0.91627907, 0.939534884, 
0.837209302, 0.818604651, 0.795348837, 0.762790698, 0.572093023, 
0.534883721, 0.553488372, 0.469767442, 0.353488372, 0.330232558, 
0.36744186, 0.358139535, 0.274418605, 0.265116279, 0.241860465, 
0.23255814, 0.176744186, 0.176744186, 0.162790698, 0.148837209, 
0.139534884, 0.125581395, 0.120930233, 0.11627907, 0.106976744, 
0.106976744, 0.106976744, 0.106976744, 0.106976744, 0.106976744, 
0.102325581, 0.093023256, 0.055813953, 0.055813953, 0.08372093, 
0.08372093, 0.079069767, 0.079069767, 0.079069767, 0.069767442, 
0.060465116, 0.060465116, 0.060465116, 0.069767442, 0, 0.001203369, 
0.004011231, 0.004813478, 0.011632571, 0.010429202, 0.023666266, 
0.028479743, 0.070998797, 0.077015644, 0.088247092, 0.0918572, 
0.201363819, 0.219013237, 0.281989571, 0.29843562, 0.503409547, 
0.555956679, 0.674288006, 0.707180104, 0.889691135, 0.922583233, 
0.935018051, 0.93622142, 0.963096671, 0.974729242, 0.98596069, 
0.98475732, 0.98475732, 0.994785399, 1, 0.997994384, 0.919775371, 
0.902527076, 0.860409146, 0.854793422, 0.756117128, 0.768953069, 
0.837545126, 0.847172082, 0.944243883, 0.963497794, 0.96550341, 
0.967107902, 0.957079824, 0.969915764, 0.955876454, 0.953469715, 
0.890894505, 0.882872042, 0.823505816, 0.805054152, 0.661452066, 
0.631768953, 0.549538708, 0.515443241, 0.300842359, 0.277978339, 
0.235058163, 0.214199759, 0.143602086, 0.139590854, 0.129161653, 
0.12755716, 0.094665062, 0.093461693, 0.088648215, 0.083433614, 
0.070998797, 0.072202166, 0.070597673, 0.07019655, 0.060569595, 
0.060569595, 0.05736061, 0.05615724, 0.038908945, 0.036101083, 
0.03449659, 0.034897714, 0.026073004, 0.02807862, 0.026073004, 
0.026073004, 0.021259527, 0.020858404, 0.016446049, 0.015643803, 
0.009225832, 0.008824709, 0.008423586, 0.008824709, 0.002406739, 
0.002005616, 0.002005616, 0.002005616, 0.009410599, 0.013372957, 
0.021297672, 0.028231798, 0.041604755, 0.044081228, 0.04952947, 
0.054482417, 0.119861317, 0.125309559, 0.161466072, 0.177810797, 
0.317483903, 0.337790986, 0.419019316, 0.438831105, 0.602278356, 
0.629024269, 0.7102526, 0.730559683, 0.873699851, 0.902922239, 
0.927686974, 0.918771669, 0.924715206, 0.95047053, 0.95789995, 
0.948489351, 0.953937593, 0.970777613, 0.992075285, 1, 0.960376424, 
0.956414066, 0.946012878, 0.929172858, 0.825160971, 0.823675087, 
0.852897474, 0.860822189, 0.902922239, 0.918276374, 0.932639921, 
0.928182268, 0.905398712, 0.921248143, 0.906884596, 0.901931649, 
0.833085686, 0.821198613, 0.778107974, 0.776126795, 0.674591382, 
0.651312531, 0.598315998, 0.566121842, 0.423972263, 0.410104012, 
0.37196632, 0.345220406, 0.256562655, 0.244180287, 0.230312036, 
0.22337791, 0.19811788, 0.193164933, 0.181773155, 0.175829619, 
0.161466072, 0.157999009, 0.146607231, 0.140663695, 0.125804854, 
0.118375433, 0.10747895, 0.100049529, 0.071817732, 0.066864785, 
0.054482417, 0.048538881, 0.035165924, 0.033184745, 0.031203566, 
0.028231798, 0.013372957, 0.010896483, 0.010401189, 0.010401189, 
0.005943536, 0.002971768, 0, 0, 0.009410599, 0.007429421, 0.003467063, 
0.000495295, 0.005997001, 0.005997001, 0.010494753, 0.005997001, 
0.031484258, 0.035982009, 0.073463268, 0.085457271, 0.127436282, 
0.136431784, 0.176911544, 0.188905547, 0.329835082, 0.374812594, 
0.425787106, 0.443778111, 0.634182909, 0.652173913, 0.743628186, 
0.772113943, 0.872563718, 0.869565217, 0.898050975, 0.899550225, 
0.931034483, 0.937031484, 0.941529235, 0.938530735, 0.950524738, 
0.985007496, 1, 0.99850075, 0.937031484, 0.925037481, 0.908545727, 
0.914542729, 0.820089955, 0.830584708, 0.847076462, 0.862068966, 
0.88155922, 0.887556222, 0.896551724, 0.887556222, 0.883058471, 
0.877061469, 0.877061469, 0.869565217, 0.824587706, 0.815592204, 
0.808095952, 0.808095952, 0.742128936, 0.712143928, 0.659670165, 
0.631184408, 0.473763118, 0.434782609, 0.409295352, 0.3988006, 
0.352323838, 0.340329835, 0.335832084, 0.338830585, 0.304347826, 
0.290854573, 0.299850075, 0.299850075, 0.283358321, 0.287856072, 
0.286356822, 0.277361319, 0.221889055, 0.221889055, 0.194902549, 
0.184407796, 0.124437781, 0.115442279, 0.083958021, 0.083958021, 
0.071964018, 0.073463268, 0.071964018, 0.070464768, 0.035982009, 
0.028485757, 0.023988006, 0.019490255, 0.017991004, 0.017991004, 
0.011994003, 0.008995502, 0.008995502, 0.007496252, 0.002998501, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -480L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), variable = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

Old:
```

[image]

```
Desired:
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `time` to `POSIXct` type and use `scale_x_datetime`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time)


ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line()+
  labs(x="Time", y="% ", title="")+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,family="Times", 
                                   face="bold", size=12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12),
        strip.text = element_text(size=6, face="bold")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = '%T', 
                   limits = c(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 07:59:59', tz = 'UTC'), 
                              as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 23:59:59', tz = 'UTC')), 
                   breaks = '1 hours')
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your explanation - but what if I would like to set the limits form 04:00 (today) to 03:00 (next day) - I tried to adjust `1970-01-01` but is still not working . Thanks

Comment: You can use `limits = c(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 08:00:00', tz = 'UTC'), as.POSIXct('1970-01-02 03:00:00', tz = 'UTC'))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `lubridate` and its function `hms`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) + geom_line()+labs(x="Time", y="% ", title="")+theme_bw()

plot + scale_x_time(limits = c(lubridate::hms("08:00:00"), lubridate::hms("24:00:00")))
```

[image]